# Svelte value assignment does not update

Tags: javascript, arrays, svelte

Why doesn't this value assignment work?

```
<script>
    let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    function addNumber() {
        numbers = numbers.push(numbers.length + 1);
    }

    $: sum = numbers.reduce((total, currentNumber) => total + currentNumber, 0);
</script>

<p>{numbers.join(' + ')} = {sum}</p>

<button on:click={addNumber}>
    Add a number
</button>
```

But when I change:

```
function addNumber() {
    numbers = numbers.push(numbers.length + 1);
}
```

to:

```
function addNumber() {
    numbers.push(numbers.length + 1);
    numbers = numbers;
}
```

it works, even though it's the same(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value) returns the new length of the array, so that is why it did not work as expected

you could also use concat or spread op instead

```
function addNumber() {
    numbers = numbers.concat([numbers.length + 1]);
}
```

```
function addNumber() {
    numbers = [...numbers, numbers.length + 1];
}
```